# Create field with sequential automatic alphanumeric name in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, virtual-field, attribute-form, autoincrement

I've created a series of layers in QGIS to collect data in field with mobile app QField. Each layer have a rule to make its names.

For example, one layer is modeled to collect corn fields. It has several attributes and its `name` field should be filled with value `C1` for the first point, `C2` for the next one and so on. I need to set the layer form with autofill sequentially. If I registered four corn points, I'll have `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, and `C4`. Once the user in field mark another corn points, the app show the form with the fifth point autofilled with `C5`, unique, not null and read-only. Later, the user has to delete `C2` and the latest points (C3, C4 and C5) got automatically updated to minus one unit (C2, C3, C4).

I've tried to create the `name` field as a virtual field and use the expression `'C' + @row_number` but apparently, `@row_number` only works with regular fields. In the Attributes Form I got no options for that, not even a PyQGis approach in the internet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful with `pyqgis` tag, without a piece of code your question can be closed ...

Answer (score 1):

'C'||if(count(@layer_id)=0,1,maximum("name")+1)

the source of knowledge:
https://stuyts.xyz/2019/10/31/how-to-autonumber-a-field-in-qgis/

---

Here are the triggers Oisin mentioned:

- CREATE TRIGGER YOUR-TABLE-NAME_keep_in_order_delete AFTER DELETE ON YOUR-TABLE-NAME
  BEGIN
  UPDATE YOUR-TABLE-NAME SET name_id = name_id-1 WHERE name_id > old.name_id;
  END
  (https://sqlite-users.sqlite.narkive.com/gdABXzam/sqlite-sql-to-renumber-values-in-a-column#post4)
- CREATE TRIGGER YOUR-TABLE-NAME_populate_name
  AFTER INSERT ON YOUR-TABLE-NAME
  BEGIN
  UPDATE YOUR-TABLE-NAME SET name = (SELECT 'C'|| "name_id") WHERE name_id = NEW.name_id;
  END
- CREATE TRIGGER YOUR-TABLE-NAME_update_name
  AFTER UPDATE OF name_id ON YOUR-TABLE-NAME
  BEGIN
  UPDATE YOUR-TABLE-NAME    SET name = (SELECT 'C'|| "name_id") WHERE OLD.name_id > NEW.name_id;
  END

With sqlitebrowser you can easily insert them into the database (ex.: geopackage). (https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Required columns in the database:

name_id INTEGER UNIQUE

name TEXT UNIQUE

In QGIS you have to use for default value:
if(count(@layer_id)=0,1,maximum("name_id")+1) ,
but don't check "Apply default value on update"

ps.
Tested with qfield, and :)))

Comment: This does not renumber after record deletion. The only way i envisage this coukd be done is with a sql trigger statement, providing this is supported by the layer type. Even then the sql is beyond me